# How to convert following into LINQ query or Object Query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to convert following into LINQ query or Object Query?

```
 SELECT ABC FROM dbo.TableOne
 WHERE XID IN (SELECT YID FROM dbo.TableTwo
 WHERE YId = 1 AND ZID2 = 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Start here: http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/sql-to-linq-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. I have not compiled it so correct the syntax errors if any.

Also you should try these things by yourself first and then post.

```
from tab1 in TableOne
where
(
    from xyz in TableTwo
    where xyz.YId == 1 && xyz.ZID2 == 2
    select xyz.YID
).Contains(tab1.XID)
select new { tab1.abc }
```

or for EF

```
var arrYID = (from xyz in TableTwo
    where xyz.YId == 1 && xyz.ZID2 == 2
    select xyz.YID).ToArray();

var objABC = from tab1 in TableOne
where arrYID.Contains(tab1.XID).select new {tab1.abc};
```

Comment: Did you tried "select new {tab1.abc}" instead of just "select tab1.abc"?

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that you are using entity framework. I have updated the answer. I have not compiled it so just correct the compile errors. Try it out.