# convert int to string in linq for searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I would like my users to be able to search for purchase orders (which are INT's) via partial strings, i.e. if a purchase order is 123456 typing in 456 gives me 123456 in the results.

I thought this would work:

```
        var pop = (from po in ctx.PurchaseOrders
               let poid = po.PurchaseOrderID.ToString()
               where poid.Contains(term)
               select new SearchItem
               {
                   id = poid,
                   label = po.SupplierID,
                   category = "purchaseorder"
               }).ToList();
```

But I get an error

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I convert the INT PurchaseOrderID to a string to enable me to search for fragments of it?

Thanks

Comment: Try a direct cast, ie `let poid = (string)po.PurchaseOrderID`. Linq to entities will honor certain method call, `ToString` is not one of them. A direct cast is logicaly equival to a `CAST(X as Type)` in SQL.

Comment: I have answered similar question here. Check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233023/how-to-convert-following-into-linq-query-or-object-query/

Comment: The solution to your problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference, have fixed this by using:

```
    var pop = ctx
    .PurchaseOrders
    .OrderBy(x => x.PurchaseOrderID)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new SearchItem()
    {
        id = x.PurchaseOrderID.ToString(),
        label = x.SupplierID,
        category = "purchaseorder"
    });
```

It's the intermediary list that makes it work.

Comment: I'd been using SqlFunctions.StringConvert all this time, but I really didn't like to create dependencies. Thank you for this solution!

Comment: The ToList will order and get all purchase orders from the database and put them in memory. If you have a lot of records, you will run in to performance issues. You should filter your records on the database side before retrieving them. Use Convert.ToString(po.PurchaseOrderID).Contains(term) as @Alberto Solano describes.

Answer (score 15):

Use this:

```
id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)poid)
```

For more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx

Comment: This will work. But it introduce a dependency between the code and the backend database (SqlFunctions will work if the EF provider is Sql Server) which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Bappi, do you mean let poid = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)po.PurchaseOrderID) if so i get an error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because your LINQ to SQL doesn't recognize the `ToString()` method.

If you want to convert an `int` to a `string` and you're using SQL Server with EF, use the function [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) in this way:

```
let poid = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)po.PurchaseOrderID);
```

or this, as alternative:

```
where Convert.ToString(po.PurchaseOrderID).Contains(term)
```

The problem is that we don't know what is the provider you're using with EF. In the case of SQL Server, this will work, but if the provider is different, like MySQL, using that expression, the application will throw an exception with this message:

> The specified method System.String StringConvert on the type
>   'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into
>   a LINQ to Entities store expression.

Be careful!

In the case you're not using SQL Server as provider, use an explicit cast in your query, as suggested by @SimonBelanger:

```
let poid = (string)po.PurchaseOrderID
```

Comment: I get: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Which provider are you using in EF? I updated my answer.

Comment: I'm using System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question and wanted to post a solution that will work with Entity Framework and LINQ to entities via Lambda expression.

```
 db.PurchaseOrders.AsEnumerable()
 .Where(x => x.PurchaseOrderID.ToString().Contains(term))
 .ToList();
```

which was borrowed from the solution here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21234785/2395030

Answer (score 0):

Linq dont know what ToString() Method is, however you can define your custom method. If you use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met), you get your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var pop = (from po in ctx.PurchaseOrders
               let poid = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)po.PurchaseOrderID)
               where poid.Contains(term)
               select new SearchItem
               {
                   id = poid,
                   label = po.SupplierID,
                   category = "purchaseorder"
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: That gives me: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.